# Expected at line 16,col 12

Tags: bootstrap-4

It keeps saying expected at line 16,col 12 and I don’t know what to do?

Screenshot:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSgT1.jpg]

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put double quotes around your url:

`url("img/tom.jpg");`